# Multiple git hooks for the same trigger

Tags: git, githooks

I have a `post-checkout` hook that I use locally in all of my repos (it renames my tmux session to `repo-name/branch-name`)

For a project I am working on, we just added a `post-checkout` hook that we're asking the whole team to use.

I don't want to add my personal hook's logic to the team-wide hook, because it's not useful to everyone, but I also don't want to give it up.

Is there a way to have more than one script execute on a single git-hook trigger? I want every `git checkout` to execute the teamwide `post-checkout` hook *and* execute my personal `post-checkout` hook. I can't have two files named the same thing -- is there a way to get around that?

**Update:** A good approach is, "make `post-checkout` call the two other scripts. I like this idea, and it may be the solution.

However, right now we have an automated setup step that copies `post-checkout` into the hooks directory. If possible, I'd like to do this in a way that *doesn't interfere* with the existing team setup, and doesn't require manual tweaking on my part if I run that install step again later.

If that's not possible, that's cool, but I'm curious about even more creative solutions.

Comment: What's wrong with renaming the two scripts and have a third one called `post-checkout` that calls them both?

Comment: If the automated setup copies some file called `post-checkout` into the `hooks` folder, that's the file that Git is going to use for that hook; there is little you can do about that. I'm afraid *some* manual tweaking on your part is required, here. After all, `post-checkout` is a client-side hook. If your team wants to enforce some policy, they should leave client-side hooks alone (they're your business, not your team's) and use server-side ones instead.

Comment: That gist does what you need: https://gist.github.com/mjackson/7e602a7aa357cfe37dadcc016710931b

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure.  Create a wrapper `post-checkout` hook script that calls the other scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh

$GIT_DIR/hooks/my-tmux-post-checkout "$@"
$GIT_DIR/hooks/corporate-post-checkout "$@"
```

You could get fancier and iterate over an arbitrary number of scripts in a `post-checkout.d` directory or something, but the basic idea is the same.

**Update for Steve**

For scripts that expect input on `stdin`:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmpfile=$(mktemp hookXXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmpfile" EXIT
cat > $tmpfile

$GIT_DIR/hooks/my-tmux-post-checkout "$@" < $tmpfile
$GIT_DIR/hooks/corporate-post-checkout "$@" < $tmpfile
```

This should actually be harmless to use for the first case as well, although if you test it by running it manually you would need to make sure you always redirect stdin from somewhere (possibly `/dev/null`).

Comment: This is a good solution, and may be the path I take. I expanded my question a bit in response; I'd love to know if there's a way to do it without interfering with the existing setup.

Comment: I don't see this as an effective way because some tools like "git review" would override the default hook trigger. The only safe way to implement this is to make git support multiple triggers itself.

Comment: `git review` only overrides the default hook trigger if you ask it to. You could manually configure the `git review` hook without a problem.  In general, I don't think *anything* should be overwriting your git hooks without your permission; if something does, that thing is broken.

Comment: Note that while this works nicely for hooks which receive parameters, such as `post-checkout`, it will not work for hooks which receive data on stdin, such as `post-receive`.

Comment: @Steve, fixed that for you.

Comment: @larsks Thanks :-)  I meant my comment not as a criticism of your original answer, but as a heads-up to others that not all hooks expect the same input.  In fact, the original answer will work with `post-receive` for the first command only (as it reads stdin), which makes debugging confusing at first.